# sql - how to select multiple columns with only one distinct column from joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server. I want to select multiple columns with only one distinct column.

For example,

TABLE 1:

```
ID    NAME  ...(other columns)
 1     A
 2     B
 3     C
```

Table 2 (ID and number together is the unique key):

```
ID    Number         Year...(other columns)
1      111           2011
2      12345678      2011
2      22222222      2012
3      333           2013
```

Table 3:

```
Name  Company       ...(other columns)
 A      Amazon    
 B      Google   
 C      Amazon
```

Each table above has many columns (more than 2). How can get the result so that there are only 5 columns as result without other "useless" columns and the ID column is the distinct column.

More specifically, for example, 
The normal sql statement I had is the following:

```
select distinct ID, NAME, NUMBER, COMPANY, Year
from table1
left join table2 on table1.ID = table2.ID
left join table3 on table1.name = table3.name
group by ID, NAME, NUMBER, COMPANY, year
order by ID desc, Year desc
```

This will output the following:

```
ID   NAME NUMBER        COMPANY  YEAR
1    A     111          Amazon   2011
2    B     12345678     google   2011
2    B     22222222     google   2012
3    c     333          Amazon   2013
```

What I want to have is actually the following:

```
ID   NAME NUMBER        COMPANY  YEAR
1    A     111          Amazon   2011
2    B     22222222     google   2012
3    c     333          Amazon   2013
```

I want to have the results without duplicated ID. If there are duplicate ID's, I want to show only the latest one. In above example, ID 2 has 2 rows in table2. I want to show the one with the latest date which is 2012.
How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have two 'google's?  The distinct select is looking at number and you have two different numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists` to only select the latest rows per id (where another row with the same id and a greater year does not exist).

```
select * from table1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from table1 t2
    where t2.id = t1.id
    and t2.year > t1.year
)
```

using analytic functions (this should be faster than the query above)

```
select * from 
  (select *,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by year desc) rn
   from table1) t1 where rn = 1
```

**edit:** applied to your tables

```
select t2.id, t3.name, t2.number, t3.company, t2.year from
(
    select * from 
    (select *,
      row_number() over(partition by id order by year desc) rn
      from table2
    ) t1 where rn = 1
) t2 join table1 t1 on t2.id = t1.id
join table3 t3 on t3.name = t1.name
```

Comment: It took a few minutes, but I was able to make your multiple-column code work for what I needed. Thank you FuzzyTree.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.NAME, t2.NUMBER, t3.COMPANY, t2.Year,
         Row_number() OVER(partition BY t1.ID, t1.NAME, t2.NUMBER, t3.COMPANY ORDER BY t2.Year DESC) AS rn
  FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.name = t3.name
)
SELECT ID, NAME, NUMBER, COMPANY, Year
FROM CTE
WHERE rownum = 1
ORDER BY ID desc, Year desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a subquery, note subqueries are inefficient.

```
select distinct t1.ID, t1.NAME, t2.NUMBER, t3.COMPANY, t2.Year
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID                        
inner join table3 t3 on t1.name = t3.name --inner join to select the latest record only
                    and t2.Year = (Select MAX(year) from table2 t22 
                                     where t22.ID = t2.Id group by ID)    
group by t1.ID, t1.NAME, t2.NUMBER, t3.COMPANY, t2.year
order by t1.ID, t2.Year desc
```

EDIT: using a more efficient CTE

```
WITH CTE as 
(
Select Id, MAX(year) as [yr] from table2 t2 group by ID
) 
select distinct t1.ID, t1.NAME, t2.NUMBER, t3.COMPANY, t2.Year
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID                        
left join table3 t3 on t1.name = t3.name
inner join CTE on cte.yr = t2.Year
                  and t2.Id = CTE.Id            
group by t1.ID, t1.NAME, t2.NUMBER, t3.COMPANY, t2.year
order by t1.ID, t2.Year desc
```